# Which is more proper: $... x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}... $ or $... x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}^3 ...$?

Tags: notation

Some books use one and some use the other. If I had to establish my own set of rules for proof writing, which one would be better?

...oh, and if possible I would be very thankful to have some... guidance on good notational conventions in general. .

Comment: I would say either $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}$ or $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @NickPeterson i mean i guess the point is to ask which of those 2 is more proper (it's just that OP forgot round brackets for 1 of them i guess)?

Comment: btw @NickPeterson what is your opinion on textbooks that refer to bases of a vector space without any brackets (reserving round brackets for ordered bases and rectangular brackets for equivalence class) ?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without more context. $x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}$ is correct for three real numbers, and $x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}^3$ is correct for three vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: In other words: Both are correct, but denote different things. I suggest that you show concrete examples from books where you have seen these notations, Then we can try to clear up your confusion.

Comment: Well, what are you trying to convey?  $x,y,z\in \mathbb R$ means $x,y,z$ are three real numbers.  Is *that* what you want to say?  $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3$ means that $(x,y,z)$ is an ordered triplet of three real numbers.  Is *that* what you want to say.  Of course if $x,y,z\in \mathbb R$ you can put them together as a triplet and $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3$.  And if $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3$ then all three are real numbers and you can break them apart and $x,y,z\in \mathbb R^3$.  Both are correct and equivalent but denote different *concepts*.  What concept are you trying to convey?

Comment: This is a little like asking which is a better way of expressing my idea:  "Perky is an elephant in the San Francisco Zoo" or "The San Francisco Zoo's collection includes an elephant specimen referred to as 'Perky'".  The question isn't which is correct but ... what do you want to convey?

Answer (score 3):

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
\text{right: } & x,y,z\in\mathbb R \\[6pt]
\text{right: } & (x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3 \\[6pt]
\text{wrong: } & \xcancel{x,y,z\in\mathbb R^3\vphantom{\int}} \\[6pt]
\text{wrong: } & \xcancel{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R\vphantom{\sum}}
\end{align}
$$

(Of course, all of this assumes that the intended meaning is the same in all four cases. The notation $x,y,z\in\mathbb R^3$ is perfectly ok if what is meant is $x= (x_1,x_2,x_3), y=(y_1,y_2,y_3), z=(z_1,z_2,z_3)\in\mathbb R^3.$)

Comment: i mean i guess the point is to ask which of those 2 is more proper (it's just that OP forgot round brackets for 1 of them i guess)?

Comment: +1 : It might also be noted that while the last line is objectively wrong (I can't even fathom a meaningful interpretation), the third line is meaningful but doesn't mean the same as the first two, so semantically it might be an error.

Comment: btw Michael Hardy what is your opinion on textbooks that refer to bases of a vector space without any brackets (reserving round brackets for ordered bases and rectangular brackets for equivalence class) ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong about $x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}^3$ if you want to introduce three vectors.

Comment: @BLCL - This is James Flores' question, it is okay to offer your interpretation, but realize your guess as to the intent may be wrong. And do not try to hijack the discussion with other questions. You can ask those in your own thread.

Comment: @BCLC : I normally think of a basis of a vector space as a set, not as a tuple. Thus $\{a,b,c,\ldots\}. \qquad$

Comment: @PaulSinclair : "BCLC" is more likely to see your comment if you spell his name correctly.